# alternative implementation of for loop for arrays

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the below piece of code. But according to the coding guidelines, the following has to be implemented without any loop(for, while are prohibited).

Can anyone help me code it using if else statements?

```
max= 0.4 / cycleTime;  //The cycle time can vary from 0.05 to 0.2
for(i = max; i>0; i--)
{
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];
    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);
    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unless `max` is guaranteed to be bounded by a small constant, coding such a thing with conditionals is absurd.  I'm inclined to guess that the prohibition on `for` and `while` is intended to elicit recursive solutions.  Have you perhaps studied recursion recently in class?  Of course, one can always hand-roll one's own loop by using a `goto` (if that's not also prohibited), but I daresay that probably wouldn't be in the spirit of the exercise.

Comment: unfortunately, even the goto statement is prohibited. Is there any chance we can use the switch or if clauses to realise the same?

Comment: Note that recursion is probably only good for max bounded by a small*ish* constant.  The limit is highly environment specific, but you probably won't successfully handle recursion deeper than a few thousand levels, if that.

Comment: There are variations on [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), but again, this or any other approach based on conditions is impractical unless `max` is certain to be *very* small.  You need to code a condition or a switch case for every one of its possible values to do the job with conditionals only.  Again, *recursion* is the approach that the exercise most likely expects you to take.

Comment: @John Bollinger, `max` is in 2..8 according to the OP, so a D's D would be quite feasible

Comment: @JohnBollinger. yeah the recursions limited to few thousands. How do I implement it?

Comment: You can lift the depth limit with [tail-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Tail-recursive_functions), see also [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: Is it an academic question? In any other case, there can't be a good reasong for such *coding guidelines*

Comment: I dont see how can I implement the tail recursion here, given that the function calls is not possible in the IDE

Comment: @jeb. No it isnt an academic question. It needs to be implemented in a real time project

Comment: What is `ArrMin.min(arr[i])`?

Comment: According to the coding guidelines, the first line doesn't need a `;`?

Comment: Even in a real time project these coding guidelines are crap! Especially when recursion is still allowed.

Comment: @joop.sorry that was a typo. corrected it

Comment: @Bob__ ArrMin is just a variable initialised to zero. ArrMin.min(arr[i]) just finds min between both of ArrMin and arr[i] element and equates ArrMin variable

Comment: @jeb: I know, but I didnt make the rules. :(

Answer (score 1):

Unrolling it and use `max` in a switch-case.
This is a Duff's device without loop.

```
i=max;
switch (max) 
{
case 8:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 7:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 6:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 5:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 4:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 3:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
case 2:
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
    arr[i]= arr[i-1];    ArrMin = ArrMin.min(arr[i]);    ArrMax = ArrMax.max(arr[i]);
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion FTW!!

```
int minimum(int *array, size_t len) {
    assert(len > 0);
    if (len == 1) {
        return *array;
    } else {
        int tmp = minimum(array + 1, len - 1);
        return tmp < *array ? tmp : *array;
    }
}
```

and similar for `maximum()`